# How to send more than one param with DelegateCommnad

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I have `Button` in `ListView` Cell. On button click I need to perform two actions from ViewModel

- Get the current record (to make modification in data)
- Get the current Cell/View (to modify text, bg color of button)

However, I am able to perform single action at a time using `DelegateCommand` by passing `Student` and `object` param respectively. See my code below

```
public StudentAttendanceListPageViewModel()
{
    //BtnTextCommand=new DelegateCommand<object>(SetBtnText);
    ItemCommand=new DelegateCommand<Student>(BtnClicked);
}

public DelegateCommand<object> BtnTextCommand { get; private set; }

public void SetBtnText(object sender)
{
    if (view.Text == "P")
    {
        view.Text = "A";
        view.BackgroundColor= (Color)Application.Current.Resources["lighRedAbsent"];               
    }
}

public DelegateCommand<Student> ItemCommand { get; }
public void BtnClicked(Student objStudent)
{
    objStudent.AbsentReasonId="1001";
    objStudent.AttendanceTypeStatusCD = "Absent";
    objStudent.AttendanceTypeStatusId = "78001"
}
```

This is `Button` code

```
<Button x:Name="mybtn"                                
    Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference ThePage}, Path=BindingContext.ItemCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"            
    BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource CaribGreenPresent}"
    Text="{Binding AttendanceTypeStatusId, Converter={x:StaticResource IDToStringConverter}}">
</Button>
```

If you see above code I have two methods `SetBtnText` and `BtnClicked`. **How can I merge these two methods into one** by passing `Student` and `object` params at a time in `DelegateCommand`?

Comment: Wait why are you sending the View into the ViewModel? Does it not defeat the whole purpose of using MVVM? Or I am confused? What is View?

Comment: Then how should I perform these two actions if I am using Prism.

Comment: On the clickevent you want the buttons to change colour and what else do you want?

Comment: I want to change text color and need the current record. You can see above code, what all I am changing in two methods.

Comment: Just add a converter for that I guess!? Adding an example give me sometime

Comment: Already I am using converter for text if button text but changing `objStudent.AttendanceTypeStatusId`(in gvn code)  not modifying button text.

Answer (score 1):

You should bind the view's properties to the view model. Then pass the view model as command parameter and change whatever you want to change in the command and data binding will automatically update the view.

Example:

```
<Button Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"
        Text="{Binding Text}">
</Button>

public class StudentViewModel
{
    public StudentViewModel( Student student )
    {
        _text = $"Kick {student.Name}";
        SomeCommand = new DelegateCommand( () => {
                                                     Text = "I have been kicked"
                                                     student.Exmatriculate();
                                                     SomeCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                                                 },
                                           () => student.IsMatriculated
                                         );
    }

    public DelegateCommand SomeCommand { get; }
    public string Text
    {
        get => _text;
        set => SetProperty( ref _text, value );
    }

    private string _text;
}
```

As stated in the comments already, *it's never ever necessary to pass the view to the view model*. To me, it looks as if you don't have a view model in the first place, though, as your code only mentions `Student` (which most likely is part of the model), while there's no occurence of a `StudentViewModel`. You know, *you do not bind to the model directly* unless it's a trivial toy project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your first paragraph very diffclt to understand :) Pl provide few lines of example so that I can understand OR write it in more detail. I am very new to MVVM.

Comment: What's unclear about "don't modify the view directly, change properties of the view model so bindings update"?